# 3 UIImageView animations with different intervals

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, uiimageview, uikit

I have 3 images which I want to show in sequence to the user. The time for moving from one to the other and the time which the images stays visible to the user is not a constant, it changes for each image. Can someone point to me the best approach to get this done? Thanks for any pointers.

To be more clear, I am looking for something like UIImageView.animationImages and then starting the animations.. *however** I want to control the time to animate in each image and the time each image stays in place before the next image animates in.

Comment: What are the time intervals?

Comment: it varies from image to image eg. From 1->2 .3s transition, stay for .5s then for 2-> 3 .2s transition stay for .4s and so on..

Answer (score 0):

A very very basic solution could be

```
- (void) showSequence{
//show image 1
//hide image 2, 3
double delay1 = 2.0;
double delay2 = 3.0;
double delay3 = 5.0;
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delay1 * NSEC_PER_SEC));
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    //hide image 1
    //show image 2
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delay2 * NSEC_PER_SEC));
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        //hide image 2
        //show image 3
        dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delay3 * NSEC_PER_SEC));
        dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
            //hide image 3
            //all 3 images has been shown
        });
    });
});
```

}

I'ts up to you to modify the code to prevent repetition

Comment: Thanks for the response.. however this does not animate though.. it shows/hides the images..

Comment: What kind of animation are you trying to achieve?

Comment: When I go from one image to the other, I need to 1) Specify the fade in duration of the next image. 2) wait for a duration before we move to the third image.

Answer (score 0):

OK, how I'd do this.

You need two image views.

```
@property UIImageView *currentImageView;
@property UIImageView *nextImageView;
```

I presume you will have some sort of model for this that includes a wait time and a transition time.

Something like this...

```
@{
    @"imageName": @"image1",
    @"waitTime": @2.0,
    @"transitionTime": @0.4
}
```

Then store these in an array something like...

```
@property NSArray *transitionImages;
```

This will make everything much easier.

Now you have a function.

```
- (void)transitionToImageAtIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
    NSDictionary *transitionImage = self.transitionImages[index];

    self.nextImageView = [UIImage imageNamed:transitionImage[@"imageName"]];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:[transitionImage[@"transitionTime"] floatValue]
                     animations:^(){
                         // crossfade between the two views
                         self.nextImageView.alpha = 1.0;
                         self.currentImageView.alpha = 0.0;
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         // swap the image views over
                         UIImageView *tempImageView = self.nextImageView;
                         self.nextImageView = self.currentImageView;
                         self.currentImageView = tempImageView;

                         // get the index of the next image
                         NSInteger nextIndex = index + 1;
                         if (nextIndex >= self.transitionImages.count) {
                             // reset to 0 if outside array bounds
                             nextIndex = 0;
                         }

                         // trigger the tradition to the next image recursively with correct delay
                         [self performSelector:@selector(transitionToImageAtIndex:) withObject:@(nextIndex) afterDelay:[transitionImage[@"waitTime"] floatValue]];
                     }];
}
```

This will work recursively and keep going forever. It won't block the UI or anything so the rest of the app will continue working.

You could also put in a check at the beginning of this method to stop it from running. This will stop the loop.